# TCP Python Socket Server Response

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, server

I'm writing a TCP python script that will act as a server and retrieve a temperature reading from a machine (the client). I need to pass a command to the client from the server and listen for an output of the response. I successfully reach the cmd definition line, but when s.accept() is called I'm left hanging with no response from the client.

Server.py

```
import socket
port = 7777
ip = raw_input('192.168.62.233')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((ip, port))
s.listen(1)
print "waiting on port: ", port

while True:
    cmd = raw_input('KRDG? A[term]')#command send to client

    conn, addr = s.accept()

    s.send(cmd)

    print "It sent"

    data = conn.recv(4096)

    print "Received:", data, " from address ", addr
```

Edit:

I believe you're correct, I should consider my code the client and temperature readout at the server. I do now get left hanging after "here 2" when I go to s.recv().

Client.py

```
import socket

ip = '192.168.62.233'
port = 7777              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ip, port))

print 'here'
s.send('KRDG? A[term]')

print 'here 2'
data = s.recv(4096)
print 'here 3'
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

Comment: normally it's the other way round: the client asks the server via command. Where's the client code?

Comment: I believe you're correct, I should consider my code the client and temperature readout at the server. I do now get left hanging after "here 2" when I go to s.recv() as seen in the edit

Comment: @ScottMacdonald So you can successfully connect to your server at ip:port, and send data to it, but you don't receive anything back. Do you have the server code? Can you check at the server whether the client data is received, and what the server does with it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a TCP server accept will block while it waits for a client to connect. Have you checked to make sure that you client can and is connecting? You could use a tool like tcpdump or similar to watch the network activity and make sure the client is connecting.